# In JavaScript: retrieve a value from html remote page + send this to another page

Tags: javascript

I know the title seems confusing, so i'll explain in details:

Using javascript i want to:

1) load page1

2) retrieve the default value of an `<input>` tag

3) send this value threw a GET parameter to page2

I hope you understand more clearly, i will edit my post if not.

Thank you for your attention

Mric

Here is an idea of the code:

```
<script>
   window.location="page1"; // redirect on page1
   var = value_of_a_TAG_on_page1; // take info from page1
   window.location="page2'+var+'\";  //send previous info to page2
</script>
```

Comment: Is page1 and page2 located below the same domain?

Comment: Not at all, they are both remote pages on different domains :-)

Comment: Most browsers will not allow you to do cross origin requests. This means you cannot request data from an other domain.

Comment: Do you own those domains and the webpages on them?

Comment: It's a challenge from the website root-me, i think in this case we are allow to do cross origin requests, page1 is a root-me page and page2 is a temporary page from "requestbin"

Comment: If you do not own the websites, you will get stuck with a cross origin request error. To solve this, you can do your GET to a PHP script, which grabs the information for you, then returns it to your Javascript function.

Comment: Thanks Snorlax, can i do my php script directly after the first window.location ?

Comment: Any chance of using c# .Net ?